# subfigure environment - how to write captions above each figure?

Tags: graphics, subfloats, subcaption

I have a set of 13 figures. I display them 4 per row in a subfigure environment.

My code:

```
\usepackage{floatrow}
\floatsetup[figure]{subcapbesideposition=top}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[label font=bf, 
            labelformat=simple]{subfig}
 \captionsetup[subfigure]{labelfont=rm}
\captionsetup[subfigure]{subrefformat=simple,labelformat=simple}
\renewcommand\thesubfigure{(\alph{subfigure})}

\begin{document}

    \begin{figure}[H]
    \centering
    \subfloat[]{\includegraphics[width=0.24\textwidth]{path to fig}} 
    \subfloat[]{\includegraphics[width=0.24\textwidth]{path to fig}} 
    \subfloat[]{\includegraphics[width=0.24\textwidth]{path to fig}}
    \subfloat[]{\includegraphics[width=0.24\textwidth]{path to fig}}
    \hfill
    \subfloat[]{\includegraphics[width=0.24\textwidth]{path to fig}}
    \subfloat[]{\includegraphics[width=0.24\textwidth]{path to fig}}
    \subfloat[]{\includegraphics[width=0.24\textwidth]{path to fig}}
    \subfloat[]{\includegraphics[width=0.24\textwidth]{path to fig}}
    \hfill
    \subfloat[]{\includegraphics[width=0.24\textwidth]{path to fig}}
    \subfloat[]{\includegraphics[width=0.24\textwidth]{path to fig}}
    \subfloat[]{\includegraphics[width=0.24\textwidth]{path to fig}}
    \subfloat[]{\includegraphics[width=0.24\textwidth]{path to fig}}
    \hfill
    \subfloat[]{\includegraphics[width=0.24\textwidth]{path to fig}}


\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

This yields captions below each figure, as in the image below:

[image: captions generated]

However, I would like the captions to be printed above each figure and give them a name instead of (a), (b), etc … Also, I need to reduce the spacings between each figure in a row.

Comment: i didn't realize floatrow supported \captonsetup and \subfloat.  It really is a world unto itself.

Comment: I would suggest also looking into the [subcaption](http://mirrors.ibiblio.org/CTAN/macros/latex/contrib/caption/subcaption.pdf) package

Answer (score 2):

Add the `position=top` parameter to `\captionsetup` command.

The following is also updated to include the requests in comments: spreading out figures evenly horizontally and naming them without numbering. See comments in the code to see what command is responsible for what.

```
\documentclass{report}

\usepackage{floatrow}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[labelformat=simple]{subfig}

% The following sets the label position to be above the figure
\captionsetup[subfigure]{position=top}

% The following disables numbering of labels (i.e., (a), (1), etc).
\renewcommand\thesubfigure{}

\begin{document}
    
    \begin{figure}[H]
        \centering
        \subfloat[your name]{\includegraphics[width=0.24\textwidth]{figure.png}}
        \hfill % <-- spreads out figure evenly horrizontally
        \subfloat[your name]{\includegraphics[width=0.24\textwidth]{figure.png}} 
        \hfill
        \subfloat[your name]{\includegraphics[width=0.24\textwidth]{figure.png}}
        \hfill
        \subfloat[your name]{\includegraphics[width=0.24\textwidth]{figure.png}}
        \\ % <-- puts a manual line break
        \subfloat[your name]{\includegraphics[width=0.24\textwidth]{figure.png}}
        \hfill
        \subfloat[your name]{\includegraphics[width=0.24\textwidth]{figure.png}} 
        \hfill
        \subfloat[your name]{\includegraphics[width=0.24\textwidth]{figure.png}}
        \hfill
        \subfloat[your name]{\includegraphics[width=0.24\textwidth]{figure.png}}
    \end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: but won't that affect the other figures in the document, which are in subfloat environment?

Comment: @sphero Yes. I was under impression you wanted it globally. Do you want me to update the answer to make captions on top per figure?

Comment: Bohatova
no problem, i confused subfloat environment with the normal figure environment. just thought that captions will also be above the figures, which is something I do not wish..
but how do i replace the (a) (b) with a custom caption?

Comment: @sphero Do you want to change the numbering, like (1), (2), (3), or do you want to add text, like (a) figure 1, (b) figure 2, (c) figure 3 ?

Comment: i want to remove any (a) or (1) - just need to add text above each figure, I also still have a bit of space between figures, I want to have it like the example you generated, however, my figures are not wide at all as yours.

Comment: @sphero I have updated the answer to include spreading the figure evenly horizontally and removing numbering. Let me know if it solves your issue!

Answer (score 0):

Your images can be organized in table, where in odd rows you insert image descriptions ("captions"), and in even rows images. For example, by use `tabularray` package for table, the code is:

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{tabularray}

\begin{document}
    \begin{figure}[ht]
    \setkeys{Gin}{width=\linewidth}
\begin{tblr}{colsep=2pt,
             colspec={@{} *{4}{X[c]} @{}},
             row{even}={belowsep=1ex},
             row{odd}={rowsep=1 pt}
             }
image name   & image name & image name & image name                     \\
\includegraphics{example-image-duck}
            & \includegraphics{example-image-duck}
                        & \includegraphics{example-image-duck}
                                    & \includegraphics{example-image-duck}  \\
image name   & image name & image name & image name                     \\
\includegraphics{example-image-duck}
            & \includegraphics{example-image-duck}
                        & \includegraphics{example-image-duck}
                                    & \includegraphics{example-image-duck}  \\
image name   & image name & image name & image name                     \\
\includegraphics{example-image-duck}
            & \includegraphics{example-image-duck}
                        & \includegraphics{example-image-duck}
                                    & \includegraphics{example-image-duck}  \\
image name   & image name & image name & image name                     \\
\includegraphics{example-image-duck}
            & \includegraphics{example-image-duck}
                        & \includegraphics{example-image-duck}
                                    & \includegraphics{example-image-duck}  \\
 \end{tblr}
   \end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Since you don't really need `\subfloat`, you can just typeset the objects within a top aligned minipage (provided the descriptions don't overshoot the image width).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[htp]
\centering

\newcommand{\namedimage}[2]{%
  \begin{minipage}[t]{0.24\textwidth}
  \centering #1 \par\smallskip \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{#2}
  \end{minipage}%
}
\newcommand{\inset}{\hspace{0.012\textwidth}}

\namedimage{desc}{example-image}\inset
\namedimage{desc}{example-image}\inset
\namedimage{desc}{example-image}\inset
\namedimage{desc}{example-image}\par\medskip

\namedimage{desc}{example-image}\inset
\namedimage{desc}{example-image}\inset
\namedimage{desc}{example-image}\inset
\namedimage{desc}{example-image}\par\medskip

\namedimage{desc}{example-image}\inset
\namedimage{desc}{example-image}\inset
\namedimage{desc}{example-image}\inset
\namedimage{desc}{example-image}\par\medskip

\namedimage{desc}{example-image}

\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]

I locally defined `\namedimage` and `\inset` in order to ease input.